# Why loading a module to a local or global variable imply in different results depending on the module in Lua?

Tags: lua

The module `lfs` seems to be accessible indifferently whether assigned to a local or global variable:

```
> lfs = require 'lfs'
> print(type(lfs))
table
```

```
> local lfs = require 'lfs'
> print(type(lfs))
table
```

The same does not occur with `md5`:

```
> md5 = require 'md5'
> print(type(md5))
table
```

```
> local md5 = require 'md5'
> print(type(md5))
nil
```

What explains the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because lfs calls `lua_setglobal(L, LFS_LIBNAME);`, which sets global `lfs` variable, so it's available even when you do `local lfs = require "lfs"`. `md5` doesn't do that.

As noted in the comments, if you run this from a Lua interpreter, you need to take into account that `local` is only visible for the same line, so running `> local a = 1` and `>print(a)` will show `nil`. It's not `nil` for `lfs` only because it also sets (implicitly) a global variable with the same name (as explained above). If you run `local mylfs = require "lfs"` and then `print(mylfs)`, the results for `lfs` and `md5` will be the same.

Comment: I suspect that the author run this code from cli.So in both cases he access to the global variable. Also, set a global variables is not recommended for mudules since Lua 5.2

Comment: Right on both counts; just `lfs` is still doing this and `md5` doesn't set the global variable.